# HP f010dx fn keys not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hp, function-keys

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 lts in my HP f010dx. Works fine except for the fn keys. I looked for drivers in driver manager but all I get is intel chip microcode

How do I enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, the fn keys were indeed working only I had to go to the BOOT settings and disable the Action keys setting. Otherwise, they did work without the fn button pressed.